# Getting sum of the amount per month - Google Sheet

Tags: google-sheets

Below is the formula where D is the amount, C is the category, and A is the month with a format of "January 1, 2020"

```
=SUMIFS(Expenses!D2:D, Expenses!C2:C, "Food", TEXT(Expenses!A2:A, "MMMM"), "January")
```

However, I am getting "Array arguments to SUMIFS are of different size."

Comment: share a copy of your sheet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use an arrayformula to make the text formula work.

Try this:

`=SUMIFS(Expenses!D2:D, Expenses!C2:C, "Food", arrayformula(TEXT(Expenses!A2:A, "MMMM")), "January")`

Be aware that Blank cells on Expenses!A2:A will output "December", to avoid that use:

`=SUMIFS(Expenses!D2:D, Expenses!C2:C, "Food", arrayformula(IF(LEN(Expenses!A2:A),TEXT(Expenses!A2:A, "MMMM"),)), "January")`

Comment: It worked. Thanks! I was wondering why there is a need to use the ArrayFormula instead of using the function TEXT directly.